# Create an Ad Creatives over LinkedIn API V2 not working

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I use the api version 2.0 and want to create an ad creatives https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives#create-a-sponsored-content-share

PHP Code

```
    POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2

    {
      "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:XXXXXXXX",
      "reference": "urn:li:share:XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE",
      "variables": {
          "data": {
              "com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables": {
                  "directSponsoredContent": true,
                  "share": "urn:li:share:XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "activity": "urn:li:activity:XXXXXXXXXXX"
              }
          }
      }
   }
```

API response

```
{"message":"Your application is not configured to access the related advertiser account(s), please ensure you have added the account ID(s) in your Account Management list.","status":403}
```

Any idea, How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with an empty object for the `SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables` variable as in the [example in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives#sample-request-1):

```
{
  "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:XXXXXXXX",
  "reference": "urn:li:share:XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "type": "SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE",
  "variables": {
      "data": {
          "com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables": {}
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Sorry! it doesn't work again now I am getting different error {"message":"Validation failed because [{field=variables, type=INVALID_VALUE, message=ERROR :: /variables/data/com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables :: record type is not backed by a DataMap, parameters={batchIndex=, key=}}, {field=/variables/data/com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables, type=INVALID_VALUE, message=Invalid value for field; wrong type or otherwise invalid input}]","status":400}

Comment: Hi @RonakShah can you share the creation payload of the sponsoredCampaign too? Could be a problem with the campaign type (should be `SPONSORED_UPDATES`)

Comment: Hi @Matteo campaign type is SPONSORED_UPDATES so no issue with that. BTW this is a known issue and Linkedin team have recognized this as a known issue and they are working on it. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for sharing :+1

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the request, you are using Ad account id which don't have access to your developer application, been faced the same issue. You need to add your account id in the developer application. its working for me.